# Are the player's Housecarls always of the opposite gender?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing a male High Elf, and currently have houses in Whiterun, Riften, and Solitude.  All of my Housecarls are female.  Additionally, I've noticed that most of the Jarls' Housecarls are also of the opposite gender.  (I believe I saw one male/male Jarl/Housecarl pairing, but I can't recall who or where.)

Is this generally the standard?  If I play a female character, will my Housecarls be male?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The Housecarls given to you are always the same, regardless of your character's gender.

Comment: The only male Housecarl I've seen was the one in Markarth. I can't say what the Windhelm housecarl's gender is, because I still can't get around that bug that prevents me from starting the quest...

Comment: Calder is also a male Nord. So that makes 2 males and 3 females.